# How to use DataPersistence to use 2 States at the same time

Tags: nrwl, nrwl-nx

I use Nx to create a new application using NgRx and DataPersistence.

I have generated several states in my application (example: State A, State B).

To retrieve the data via an API request to populate State A, I use in the effect associated with this.dataPersistence.fetch.

However to launch my API request, I need data contained in State B.
This is where I block.

I saw that by using the basic effects, we can use the "withLastestFrom" operator to retrieve a different state than the one currently used.

```
@Injectable()
export class ElementEffects {
constructor (private store: Store<any>, private apiService: ApiService) {}

      @Effect()
      public yourEffect: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<yourActionClass>(ActionsEnum.YOUR_ACTION),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectSomethingFromTheStore))),
        concatMap(([action, selectedDateFromTheStore]) => this.apiService.doBackendCall(selectedDateFromTheStore, action.payload).pipe(
          map(([resultFromTheBackendCall, selectedDateFromTheStore]) => {
            // Do Stuff
          },
          catchError((error) => of(new FailureAction(error)))
          )
        ),
      );
}
```

However I do not know how to handle that with this.dataPersistence.fetch.

By opening the DataPersistent code (https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/angular/src/runtime/nx/data-persistence.ts), I see that the `fetch` feature is already using the `withLatestFrom` operator. I do not see how to recover another State.

```
  fetch<A extends Action = Action>(
    actionType: string,
    opts: FetchOpts<T, A>
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType<A>(actionType),
      withLatestFrom(this.store),
      fetch(opts)
    );
  }
```

My question is therefore:
How to recover State B when I use a State A effect?

Hoping to be clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from `data-persistence.d.ts`

```
@Injectable()
class TodoEffects {
  @Effect() loadTodo = this.s.navigation(TodoComponent, {
    run: (a, state) => {
      console.log(state); // Here you should see all the states in your app
      return this.backend.fetchTodo(a.params['id']).map(todo => ({
        type: 'TODO_LOADED',
        payload: todo
      }));
    },
    onError: (a, e: any) => {
      // we can log and error here and return null
      // we can also navigate back
      return null;
    }
  });
  constructor(private s: DataPersistence<TodosState>, private backend: Backend) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes `fetch` will return the entire state store.

So you will need to pick what part (slice) of the store you want to use:

```
const state1 = state['state1'];
const state2 = state['state2'];
```

As `withLatestFrom` pull the "latests" state of the store.